# Not able to update Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: updates

I have Ubuntu 12.04. But every time, I want to update, it does not work. It says, I am not connected to the internet. But this is wrong, I am connected. 
This is the text:

```
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-l10n_24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg_24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lightdm/lightdm_1.2.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/gnome-control-center-data_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.9_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lightdm/liblightdm-gobject-1-0_1.2.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity-greeter/unity-greeter_0.2.9-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-globalmenu_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_11.2.202.262-0precise1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Failed to fetch http:archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.262-0precise1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/libgnome-control-center1_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.9_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/deja-dup/deja-dup_22.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-branding_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-gnome-support_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-de_18.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-control-center/gnome-control-center_3.4.2-0ubuntu0.9_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-common_1.11.4-0ubuntu10.11_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-core_1.11.4-0ubuntu10.11_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-generic_3.2.0.37.45_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-image-generic_3.2.0.37.45_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
Failed to fetch http:de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-headers-generic_3.2.0.37.45_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.13.10 80]
```

After each "http:" there is "//", but I am not allowed to post more than 2 links, so I left it away, because now it is not declared as a link. I hope, you can still know, what I mean. I have also an image, but I am not allowed to post it either. So I copied the text. 
The headline is "Das Herunterladen der Paketdateien ist gescheitert. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Internetverbindung." Means: the downloading of the packet data was not successful. Please check your connection to the internet." (I hope, it´s correctly translated, I am not very good at english)
I hope, you can help me! I am really desperate. 
Thank you in advance!
Kathrin

Comment: Are you able to browse the internet?

Comment: Yes, I am, as you see right now ;) I have tried it minutes before and browsed before and after the trial.

Comment: yes, I can see the page.

Comment: Can you please show /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: show? I don´t know, what you mean...

Comment: You can copy and paste the contents of it, in the question...

Comment: I´m sorry, that I still don´t understand. Where do I find /etc/apt/sources.list? Is this an url? I don´t really know...

Comment: Its a file on your computer. You can use gedit to open that file.

Comment: I wanted to install gedit, but now I have the same problem. It cannot be installed, because it says I´m not connected to the internet.

Comment: Can you please execute this command and show me the output here? `lsb_release -c | cut -f 2`

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe because you're using a German mirror. Just go to the update manager settings, to "Ubuntu Software" and change the mirror/server.
You can also just edit /etc/apt/sources.list by deleting the "de".

This is the German link:http://blog.fbausch.de/2012/03/17/ubuntu-12-04-repository-probleme/

Comment: etc/apt/source.list should have the following link:
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
please change to
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Comment: I have found Ubuntu Software Center. I searched there for "mirror" and found this: "Keeps FTP arcieves up-to-date" version mirror 2.9-59 I can install this programme for free.

Comment: I am sorry. Go to the update manager and then to settings. A window will open which name in German is "Software Paketquellen". Then go to "Software von Ubuntu" on left side and choice another Server.

Comment: You will find the update manager in the same drop down menu where you also shut down your computer...

Comment: Is this "Synaptics Paketverwaltung"? I don´t know how to translate this. I have clicked on this link with de.archive... and I deleted in the browser the "de." Now it says "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at archive.ubuntu.com Port 80" instead of "Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at de.archive.ubuntu.com Port 80"

Comment: Ok, I think the easiest way would be to change the setting in the Update manager. Just follow my instruction above.

German: Klicke auf der rechten oberen Seite auf das Zahnrad und klicke dann auf das, bei dir vermutlich rote Feld, mit für die Updates. Dann erscheint das Aktualisierungsfenster, welches bei dir nicht funktioniert. Klicke unten links auf Einstellungen und dann auf den Reiter "Software von Ubuntu". Dort kannst du das Feld "Herunterladen von" ändern von "Server für Deutschland" zu einem anderen Land...

Comment: Which country shall I choose? Or it doesn´t matter which? All except German?

Comment: there is also a mirror server: mirrors.ubuntu.com. Shall I choose this one?

Comment: Just choice the mirrors.ubuntu.com one

Comment: Yes!! It works!! Thank you thank you thank you!!! I´m so happy!!! Thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer by clicking on the green button next to my answer. This is how we say thank you on this website.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in my blog post [here](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/05/fixing-ubuntu-apt-get-sources.html), you can run these commands, from a terminal, to fix this problem

```
wget -O UpdateAptSources.sh http://ideone.com/plain/UgsBel
chmod 555 UpdateAptSources.sh
sudo ./UpdateAptSources.sh
```